# I am trying to insert text into a rich text area field which has string '\\n' in the text. However salesforce is ignoring everything after \\n. Ideas?

Tags: richtextarea

I am trying to insert text into a rich text area field which has string '\\n' in the text. However salesforce is ignoring everything after '\\n'. This is basically a chat transcript coming from another system and there are multiple instances of '\\n'. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For the rich text field you will need to use HTML equivalent of new line. You will have to **replace** the **\n with br** in your code.

Please try below:

```
String s = 'Test \n String';
s.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Before inputting the data into that field, I would replace all occurrences of `\\n` with `<br/>`. Alternatively, you could enclose the data in `<pre></pre>` tags.